# How to obtain p-values and CI for the effect of interaction item using GLM in R

Tags: r, regression, glm, interaction

In a multivariable GLM model, I need to calculate the simple effects of the following interaction item:
sex (female vs. male)*unstablyhoused (yes vs. no)

The model has as.factor variables, with my reference variables being Male = 1, unstably housed (no) = 0.
In my model, female = 2 and unstably housed (yes) = 1

I have written the following code but not sure how can I calculate the OR's, CI, and different p-values for each of the categories stated above.

```
model <- glm(depression ~ as.factor(unstablyhoused) + as.factor(SEXBRTH) + as.factor(unstablyhoused)*as.factor(SEXBRTH), 
             data=mergedata, family = binomial(link='logit'), na.action = na.omit)
summary(model)
confint(model)
exp(coef(model))
exp(cbind(OR = coef(model), confint(model)))
```

My question is how do I calculate the OR, confidence interval (95% CI), and p-values for the effect of the interaction when:

1. sex(female vs. male) among those who are unstably housed
2. sex (female vs. male) among those who do NOT unstably housed
3. unstablyhoused (yes vs. no) among those that are female
4. unstablyhoused (yes vs. no) among those that are NOT female

Any help and direction in what code to use to be able to calculate 1-4 items, would be greatly appreciated. I need to know the OR, confidence intervals, and p-value of the simple main effects

ModelOutput
[image: 1]

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example with an example output of your data. Also, check that your categorical variables `sex` and `unstablyhoused` are in factor format. Your output suggest that the model is treating both as continuous measures at the moment. The summary is there to help you construct a prediction model in the vein of gad7ms = 1.3*unstablyhoused*sex - 0.39*sex + 0.64*violence6mo + 0.26*city -0.26*unstablyhoused + 0.07. You can use predict function to derive the value directly of course.

Comment: Hi @AdamQuek, thank you so much for your response! I fixed the model and converted my variables as.factor. I am trying to measure depression but specifically, I am trying to understand the effect of the interaction item when sex = female among those who are unhoused = 1, when sex = female among those who are not unhoused = 0, when those who are unhoused =1 are female = 2, and when those who are unhoused = 1 are not female = 1. Thank you for any tips you can provide me! The output of model is hyperlinked.

Comment: Can't really start to give you anything as there's no "standard" way of understanding/visualizing interaction effects. Maybe [this](http://www.sthda.com/english/articles/40-regression-analysis/164-interaction-effect-in-multiple-regression-essentials/) can help you?